# I am new to coding. I would like to display my java code result from my javascript file in a text box on my html page after pressing a button

Tags: javascript, html

//This is my my html. I have created a textbox that I want my javascript code to display inside after pressing the "yes" button which activates the script. I also have two color selectors on the html page which I want to somehow link to the two color inputs in my javascript code. Help appreciated!/*

```
<!doctype html>
    <html>
<link rel="stylesheet"href="styles.css">

            <h1> New color Options </h1>

            <h3> Choose your color </h3>

            </body>

            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>
            <br></br>

            
            <script src="colors.js"></script>
        

            

            <br>
            <input type="text" id="textb">
            <p id="results"></p>
            <input type="button" value="Select" onclick="revme()">



            <!-- this is the box -->
            <div id="mybox" class="box">
                    <label for="mybox"> </label>
                    <output name="mybox" type="text"><br>
            </div>
                    
            <button onclick="ab()">Yes</button>

            <div class="testing">

                <script>
                    function ab() {
                    document.getElementById("mybox").innerHTML = tests()
                    }
                </script>

            </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

//Here is my javascript//

function tests()
{

```
let age = ("blue") + ("blue");



if(age == "blue" + "blue"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Water Blue";

}

else if(age == "blue" + "yellow"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Green";
}

else if(age == "blue" + "red"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Purple";
}

else if(age == "blue" + "green"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Turquoise";
}

else if(age == "blue" + "white"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Light Blue";
}

else if(age == "yellow" + "yellow"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Cheese Yellow";
}

else if(age == "yellow" + "blue"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Green";
}

else if(age == "yellow" + "red"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Orange";
}

else if(age == "yellow" + "green"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Lime";
}

else if(age == "yellow" + "white"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Light yellow";
}

else if(age == "green" + "green"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "grass green";
}

else if(age == "green" + "yellow"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "lime green";
}

else if(age == "green" + "blue"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "Turquoise";
}

else if(age == "green" + "red"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "brown";
}

else if(age == "green" + "white"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "light green";
}

else if(age == "red" + "red"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "blood red";
}

else if(age == "red" + "blue"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "purple";
}

else if(age == "red" + "green"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "brown";
}

else if(age == "red" + "yellow"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "orange";
}
else if(age == "red" + "white"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "pink";
}

else if(age == "white" + "white"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "paper white";
}

else if(age == "white" + "red"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "pink";
}

else if(age == "white" + "blue"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "light blue";
}

else if(age == "white" + "green"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "light green";
}

else if(age == "white" + "yellow"){
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "light yellow";
}

else {
    document.getElementById("new").innerHTML = "None";
}
```

}

Comment: There is no java code which you want to display. I think you simply want to display colors in 'mybox'  on click of 'Yes' button. Please confirm.

Comment: i want to display the javascript result text which is calculated after the javascript runs in the text box. If it runs correctly it should display "Water Blue" in the text box.

Comment: `java` != `javascript`...

Comment: @paulodavid04, I have added code below as per my understanding of your problem. Please run it and let me know if the understanding is correct.

Comment: yes thats perfect. thankyou so much for your help. I can learn alot from this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though this code has enough scope of improvement, still you can do something like this.

```js
function tests(){

    let selectedValue= document.getElementById("blendedColor").value;
    let blendedColor;

if(selectedValue == '"blue" + "blue"'){
    blendedColor = "Water Blue";
} else if(selectedValue == '"blue" + "yellow"'){
    blendedColor = "Green";
} else if(selectedValue == '"blue" + "red"'){
    blendedColor= "Purple";
} else if(selectedValue == '"blue" + "green"'){
    blendedColor = "Turquoise";
} else if(selectedValue == '"blue" + "white"'){
    blendedColor = "Light Blue";
} else if(selectedValue == '"yellow" + "yellow"'){
    blendedColor = "Cheese Yellow";
} else if(selectedValue == '"yellow" + "blue"'){
   blendedColor = "Green";
} else if(selectedValue == '"yellow" + "red"'){
    blendedColor = "Orange";
} else if(selectedValue == '"yellow" + "green"'){
   blendedColor = "Lime";
} else if(selectedValue == '"yellow" + "white"'){
    blendedColor = "Light yellow";
} else if(selectedValue == '"green" + "green"'){
    blendedColor = "grass green";
} else if(selectedValue == '"green" + "yellow"'){
    blendedColor = "lime green";
} else if(selectedValue == '"green" + "blue"'){
    blendedColor= "Turquoise";
} else if(selectedValue == '"green" + "red"'){
    blendedColor = "brown";
} else if(selectedValue == '"green" + "white"'){
    blendedColor = "light green";
} else if(selectedValue == '"red" + "red"'){
    blendedColor = "blood red";
} else if(selectedValue == '"red" + "blue"'){
    blendedColor= "purple";
} else if(selectedValue == '"red" + "green"'){
    blendedColor = "brown";
} else if(selectedValue == '"red" + "yellow"'){
    blendedColor = "orange";
} else if(selectedValue == '"red" + "white"'){
    blendedColor = "pink";
} else if(selectedValue == '"white" + "white"'){
    blendedColor = "paper white";
} else if(selectedValue == '"white" + "red"'){
    blendedColor = "pink";
} else if(selectedValue == '"white" + "blue"'){
    blendedColor = "light blue";
} else if(selectedValue == '"white" + "green"'){
    blendedColor = "light green";
} else if(selectedValue == '"white" + "yellow"'){
    blendedColor = "light yellow";
} else {
     blendedColor = "None";
}
   document.getElementById("mybox").innerHTML = blendedColor
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="colors.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">

</head>
        </body>

            <h1> New color Options </h1>

            <h3> Choose your color </h3>
            
            <br></br>

            
            <br>
            <select name="blendedColor" id="blendedColor">
                <option>Select Value</option>
                <option value='"blue" + "blue"'>"blue" + "blue"</option>
                <option value='"blue" + "yellow"'>"blue" + "yellow"</option>
                <option value='"blue" + "red"'>"blue" + "red"</option>
                <option value='"blue" + "green"'>"blue" + "green"</option>
                <option value='"blue" + "white"'>"blue" + "white"</option>
                <option value='"yellow" + "yellow"'>"yellow" + "yellow"</option>
                <option value='"yellow" + "blue"'>"yellow" + "blue"</option>
                <option value='"yellow" + "red"'>"yellow" + "red"</option>
                <option value='"yellow" + "green"'>"yellow" + "green"</option>
                <option value='"yellow" + "white"'>"yellow" + "white"</option>
            </select>
            <p id="results"></p>
            <!-- this is the box -->
            <div id="mybox" class="box">
                    <label for="mybox"> </label>
                    <output name="mybox" type="text"><br>
            </div>
                    
            <button onclick="tests()">Yes</button>

            <div class="testing">           
            </div>

        </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few issues with your code:

- the `<output>` element needs a closing tag,
- an expression like `("blue")+("blue")` can be simplified to `"blueblue"`
- the `if-else` chain can be written much more easily by using a map or a simple object (see below: `blended`).
- and last but not least you should follow the DRY principle: don't repeat yourself and do the expression `document.getElementById("new").innerHTML=...` only once, with a previously calculated value.

```js
function test(a,b){
  const blended={blueblue:"Water Blue",blueyellow:"Green",blured:"Purple",bluegreen:"Turquoise",bluewhite:"Light blue",yellowyellow:"Cheese Yellow",yellowblue:"Green",yellowred:"Orange",yellowgreen:"Lime",yellowwhite:"Light yellow",greengreen:"grass green",greenyellow:"lime green",greenblue:"Turquoise",greenred:"brown",greenwhite:"light green",redred:"blood red",redblue:"purple",redgreen:"brown",redyellow:"orange",redwhite:"pink",whitewhite:"paper white",whitered:"pink",whiteblue:"light blue",whitegreen:"light green",whiteyellow:"light yellow"};
  return blended[a+b] || "None";
}

document.querySelector("#mybox output").textContent=test("green","yellow");
```

```html
<div id="mybox" class="box">
  <label for="mybox">The blended colour is </label>
  <output name="mybox" type="text"><br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch`&`case` instead of `if`&`else`

Additionally, you **don't need** to define a `value` for each `option`. To understand how `select` works without `value`, pay attention the following HTML code:

```js
function fun(){
   var obj = document.getElementById("blendedColor");
   var c;
   switch(obj.options[obj.selectedIndex].text){
        case '"blue" + "blue"': c="Water Blue"; break;
        case '"blue" + "yellow"': c="Green"; break;
        case '"blue" + "red"': c="Purple"; break;
        case '"blue" + "green"': c="Turquoise"; break;
        case '"blue" + "white"': c="Light Blue"; break;
        case '"yellow" + "yellow"': c="Cheese Yellow"; break;
        case '"yellow" + "blue"': c="Green"; break;
        case '"yellow" + "red"': c="Orange"; break;
        case '"yellow" + "green"': c="Lime"; break;
        case '"yellow" + "white"': c="Light yellow"; break;
        case '"green" + "green"': c="grass green"; break;
        case '"green" + "yellow"': c="lime green"; break;
        case '"green" + "blue"': c="Turquoise"; break;
        case '"green" + "red"': c="brown"; break;
        case '"green" + "white"': c="light green"; break;
        case '"red" + "red"': c="blood red"; break;
        case '"red" + "blue"': c="purple"; break;
        case '"red" + "green"': c="brown"; break;
        case '"red" + "yellow"': c="orange"; break;
        case '"red" + "white"': c="pink"; break;
        case '"white" + "white"': c="paper white"; break;
        case '"white" + "red"': c="pink"; break;
        case '"white" + "blue"': c="light blue"; break;
        case '"white" + "green"': c="light green"; break;
        case '"white" + "yellow"': c="light yellow"; break;
        default: c= "None";
   }
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = c
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
      <head>
         <script src="colors.js"></script>
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
      </head>
      </body>
         <select name="blendedColor" id="blendedColor">
            <option>Select Value</option>
            <option>"blue" + "blue"</option>
            <option>"blue" + "yellow"</option>
            <option>"blue" + "red"</option>
            <option>"blue" + "green"</option>
            <option>"blue" + "white"</option>
            <option>"yellow" + "yellow"</option>
            <option>"yellow" + "blue"</option>
            <option>"yellow" + "red"</option>
            <option>"yellow" + "green"</option>
            <option>"yellow" + "white"</option>
         </select>
         <p id="results">Please Query TO Show This</p>
         <button onclick="fun()">Query</button>
      </body>
   </html>
```